# Selenium Select can't find option by Text in HTML select element

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code lines to select an insurance type (soortVerzekering) from a list:

```
public void SelecteerSoortVerzekering(string soortVerzekering)
{        
    var insurance = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("insurance"));          
    var selectElement = new SelectElement(insurance);
    IList<IWebElement> optionList = selectElement.Options; // added only to inspect the elements in the select
    selectElement.SelectByText(soortVerzekering);
}
```

When running this code the following exception appeared:  OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : *Cannot locate element with text: 'Fietsverzekering'*. When debugging I can see that the Select element is found and an option with the wanted insurance type is present.

[image]

I used exactly the same piece of code in another project where it's working fine.

The only difference is the versions of Selenium and Selenium Support, in the failing project 4.8.0 in the project where the test succeeds 3.141.0.

Comment: you may need to click on the select element first to open the menu.  Right-now it looks like that option has a 0,0 size.  The selectByText method may only check for visible text.

Comment: All the examples given in the Selenium documentation shows that you have to locate the Select element, use it to initialize a Select object and then execute the desired method on the Select object e.g. 'SelectByText'. This is working fine for me in another project using the same code on the same HTML page. Today I discovered that when calling the SelectByText method and passing the actual value "Fietsverzekering" directly instead by passing the method argument is working without problem but of course that is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the sreenshot the argument soortVerzekering (first yellow arrow) contains extra single quotes which causes the mismatch selecting the desired option in the HTML.This was caused by the way the parameters were passed from the parent specflow scenario.